# createjs.Shape() doesn't work with OOP JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, shapes, createjs

I'm trying to start the shape var in my Paddle class in JavaScript but it doesn't want to render it. The code works fine if I define the shape var in the init function.

Code

```
var Paddle = function(sizeX, sizeY){
    var posX, posY;
    var sizeX, sizeY;

    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;

    shape = new createjs.Shape();
}

var paddle1 = new Paddle(25, 75);

function init(){

    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

    //shape = new createjs.Shape();
    paddle1.shape.graphics.beginFill("blue").drawRect( 15, 0, paddle1.sizeX, paddle1.sizeY);

    stage.addChild(paddle1.shape);

    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', stage);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', update);
}

function update(){

    stage.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are calling `init()` (which isn't shown in your code), then you'll see an error in your console that `paddle1.shape` is not an object. That is because you forgot `this`.

```
this.shape = new createjs.Shape();
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/gskinner/Lz33kaqb/

Comment: Thank You so much, i'm coming from C# and the this tag is not needed in making a object's var

Comment: Gotcha. In JS it's always a good idea to use an explicit scope, otherwise you'll (usually) wind up in the window scope.